# Executing asynchronous function , synchronously

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension that blocks specific sites added to local storage through popup window. I think the problem in this code is, it returns before completion of chrome.storage.local.get's callback. How can I make it wait for sometime before returning ?

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
function(details) {

var matched = false;

chrome.storage.local.get ( 'blocked_sites', function ( sites ) {
   var bsites = sites.blocked_sites;
   for ( i = 0, size = bsites.length; i < size; i++ ) {
    if ( details.url.indexOf( "://" + bsites[i] + "/" ) != -1 ) {
      matched = true;
    } // end if 
  } // end for

});
// WAIT HERE FOR VALUE OF MATCHED TO BE SET BY CALLBACK
return { cancel: matched };
},
{ urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
["blocking"] );

chrome.storage.local.set({'blocked_sites': [ 'www.topnotchdev.com'] }, null);
```

Comment: You cannot make it wait. You can only rewrite your code to be async as well.

Comment: yes, I tried to make it wait by using a loop and it blocked the thread. tell me how can I rewrite it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call *any* asynchronous function in `webRequest` blocking listeners. There is no way around it, hacky or otherwise. It is fundamentally impossible, since JavaScript is single-threaded; an async operation won't even *start* before the current function finishes executing.

This means you cannot rely on asynchronous storage; you must have a local synchronous cache for it.

Save `blocked_sites` to a variable, and update it on `chrome.storage.onChanged` event. This way, you'll have a synchronous cache of the setting.

Comment: Thanks for quick response @Xan . but local variable will destroy after execution of script, how will I populate it on next execution of script ?

Comment: From `chrome.storage`. Just don't call `chrome.storage` while in that `webRequest` listener.

Comment: Posting comments in the code doesn't work either. Make a new question (since this one already received a few answers). And before you do, try to think a bit about it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

With the way your code structured you won't be able to make `return { cancel: matched };` execute after the callback. The reason is because `return { cancel: matched };` is run in one execution frame ( the same that calls `chrome.storage.local.get` ) and the callback is run in some future execution frame. When you call asynchronous method it can only insert the callback into event loop for some future time, by the time that callback is executed `return { cancel: matched };` is already executed.